# Event listener when the transformation of the stream is finished, Node.js

Tags: node.js

> I am trying to register event listener at the end of the data in pipe transformation. I was
>   trying register the event to all streams in a pipe:

a) my custom transform stream (StreamToBuffer)
b) standard file read stream
c) standard gunzip stream.

> But unfortunately, none of them works (see code below). As far as I
>   try, only 'data' event works, but it does not help.

What I need is to continue with processing of the *tailBuffer* in *StreamToBuffer* class **after** the transformation is finished.

Can you suggest how to achive this?

The code (simplified for brevity):

```
function samplePipe() {
    var streamToBuffer = new StreamToBuffer();
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(bgzFile1, { flags: 'r',
        encoding: null,
        fd: null,
        mode: '0666',
        autoClose: true
    });
    var gunzipTransform = zlib.createGunzip();
    readStream.on('end', function() {
        //not fired
        console.log('end event readStream');
    });
    streamToBuffer.on('end', function() {
        //not fired
        console.log('end event streamBuffer');
    });
    gunzipTransform.on('end', function() {
        //not fired
        console.log('end event gunzipTransform');
    });
    readStream
        .pipe(gunzipTransform)
        .pipe(streamToBuffer)
    ;
}
```

StreamToBuffer:

```
function StreamToBuffer() {
    stream.Transform.call(this);
    this.tailBuffer = new Buffer(0);
}

util.inherits(StreamToBuffer, stream.Transform);

StreamToBuffer.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this.tailBuffer = Buffer.concat([this.tailBuffer, chunk]); 
    console.log('streamToBuffer');
}

StreamToBuffer.prototype._flush = function(callback) {
    callback();
}

module.exports = StreamToBuffer;
```

**EDITED:**
After playing a little with passing callback function to StreamToBuffer constructor, I have discovered the mistake - missing *callback();* in *_transform()* method. After adding it, the event 'end' listener  works, at least on standard read stream.

```
StreamToBuffer.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this.tailBuffer = Buffer.concat([this.tailBuffer, chunk]); 
    console.log('streamToBuffer');
    callback();
}
```

Another way is to pass callback function to StreamToBuffer constructor and then call it in *_flush* method. This has the advantage that we can be sure that the transformation is completed.

```
function samplePipe() {
    var streamToBuffer = new StreamToBuffer(processBuffer);
.....
}

function processBuffer(buffer) {
    console.log('processBuffer');
}
```

StreamToBuffer:

```
function StreamToBuffer(callback) {
    stream.Transform.call(this);
    this.tailBuffer = new Buffer(0);
    this.finishCallback = callback;
}

util.inherits(StreamToBuffer, stream.Transform);

StreamToBuffer.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this.tailBuffer = Buffer.concat([this.tailBuffer, chunk]); 
    console.log('streamToBuffer');
    callback();
}

StreamToBuffer.prototype._flush = function(callback) {
    console.log('flushed');
    callback();
    this.finishCallback(this.tailBuffer);
}

module.exports = StreamToBuffer;
```

ALthough I did not receive any answer yet (thanks for other comments, anyway), I think this question can be useful for the people like me, who are learning node. If you know better solution, pls answer. Thank you.

Comment: I think the best way is to use promise: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: In these cases, it is often reasonable that you answer your own question below, instead of having a question that answers itself.

Answer (score 0):

For writable stream, try `finish` event instead of `end` event:

```
streamToBuffer.on('finish', function() {
  // finish event fired
});
```